# How to use global variable - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to use global variable in dart/flutteer?

```
class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  // UserPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  final int userId; //my variable

  UserPage({@required this.userId});

  @override
  UserPageState createState() => UserPageState();
}
```

I want use this variable like a parameter in my method in url

```
Future<User> getCurrentUser() async {
    var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:80/user/';
    var response = await http.get(url);

    print(response.statusCode);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var userJson = json.decode(response.body);
      print(userJson);
      return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      print('dupa');
      // throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
```

Comment: is the getCurentUser inside the UserPageState class ?

Comment: @AhmedKhattab, yes, is in this class

Comment: You have statefull widget... try to call it widget.dupa

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following your question. Are you trying to insert your global variable into your url string? If so, `var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:80/user/' + globalVar;` or `var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:80/user/$globalVar';`. Apologies if that's not what you're asking

Comment: @delmin, I do not understand what you are talking about, could you describe with an example in the new post?

Comment: @buttonsrtoys, it throw me that my variable in string is undefined, but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `widget` variable that is available inside state classes,

in your case you can aceess the userId using

```
 Future<User> getCurrentUser() async {
    var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:80/user/{widget.userid}';
    var response = await http.get(url);

    print(response.statusCode);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var userJson = json.decode(response.body);
      print(userJson);
      return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      print('dupa');
      // throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
```

Comment: it work, thanks :), btw. after run this function my console show me: ```Class 'User' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'User'
Tried calling: []("firstName")```, in which is problem?, i don't declare array?

Comment: how to declare array in my model?

Comment: it seems your json response is empty

Comment: no, response is not empty, in console log throw me ```order: []```, because of this my function doesn't start

Comment: i don't know how to declare it in my model

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access an instance variable inside the method of the state class, you can use widget.variableName. So here you can use widget.userId and you can define your url as below:

```
Future<User> getCurrentUser() async {
    var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:80/user/${widget.userId}';
    var response = await http.get(url);

    print(response.statusCode);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var userJson = json.decode(response.body);
      print(userJson);
      return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      print('dupa');
      // throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Pleas upvote my answer if it solves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: btw. after run this function my console show me: ```Class 'User' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'User'
Tried calling: []("firstName")```, in which is problem?, i don't declare array?

Comment: how to declare array in my model?

Comment: I think that's a different question as it is a problem with the User class.